# WifiInfo returning null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi, ssid, android-connectivitymanager

I have been working on this for a few days after following this [guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-monitor-internet-connection-in-android-using-kotlin-and-livedata-135de9447796) online. I am using target API 30 (building on a device using Android 11). Trying to get the Wifi SSID using `networkCapabilities` this keeps returning null whereas the depreciated `wifiManager.connectionInfo.ssid` returns the correct SSID. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I know this will need to change for API 31 to include the `FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO` but I believe this should be working for API 30. Any ideas?

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.net.NetworkRequest
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

private const val TAG = "NetworkStatus"

enum class NetworkStatus {
    UNAVAILABLE,
    CONNECTED_TO_XXXX,
    CONNECTED_TO_OTHER,
    CONNECTION_LOST
}

 class NetworkStatusHelper(private val context: Context) : LiveData<Pair<NetworkStatus, String>>() {

private lateinit var connectivityManagerCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

val wifiManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

private fun getConnectivityManagerCallback() = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    override fun onUnavailable() {
        super.onUnavailable()
        announceStatus(Pair(NetworkStatus.UNAVAILABLE, ""))
    }

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        super.onAvailable(network)

    }

    override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
        network: Network,
        networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
    ) {
        super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)

        Log.d(TAG, "onCapabilitiesChanged: transport info = ${connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)?.transportInfo}")
        try {
            val wifiInfo = networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo
            
            Log.d(TAG, "onCapabilitiesChanged: wifi SSID ${wifiInfo}")

            if (wifiInfo.ssid.contains("XXXX-")) {
                announceStatus(Pair(NetworkStatus.CONNECTED_TO_XXXX, wifiInfo.ssid))
            } else {
                announceStatus(Pair(NetworkStatus.CONNECTED_TO_OTHER, wifiInfo.ssid))
            }

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCapabilitiesChanged: exception = $e")
        }

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCapabilitiesChanged: ${wifiManager.connectionInfo.ssid}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAvailable: exception = $e")
        }

    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        super.onLost(network)
        announceStatus(Pair(NetworkStatus.CONNECTION_LOST, ""))
    }

}

fun announceStatus(networkResposePair: Pair<NetworkStatus, String>) {
    postValue(networkResposePair)
}

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    connectivityManagerCallback = getConnectivityManagerCallback()
    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .build()
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, connectivityManagerCallback)
}

override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(connectivityManagerCallback)
}
}
```

Permissions in Gradle:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

SDK versions

```
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    minSdkVersion 30
    targetSdkVersion 31
```

Answer (score -1):

When creating your `NetworkCallback` object, try pass to the constructor `FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO` like so:

```
object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO) { /* your code */ }
```

This way we are telling that we want to receive some sensitive data about the network, but it will work only with API level 31 and higher sadly.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO)

Comment: Thanks, my intention if I ever plan to move up to Android 12 is include requires=api version. This statement seems to return null "val wifiInfo = networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo" maybe I am doing something wrong here. I have also just seen that I need to include a foreground service type so will attempt that.

Comment: @958 For API level less than 31 you try to use `WifiManager` from `systemService` of your app context. And from this manager retrieve `WifiInfo`. For that your would need to add build versions check of the device.